# Should I define models that will be owned by many different models or use controller and views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am struggling to figure out how to get a relationship between several models. I have sales_leads which I need to view by company and by event. So, if someone looks up the company leads they can see everything across all events, but also see all leads by event.  Not sure if this is ownership versus a where?

Should it be something like

```
Company.sales_leads where("event.event_id = ?", "2356")
```

Or Models:

```
  sales_lead
  belongs_to event
  belongs_to company
```

Comment: Do you have any further code you could share - your models would be good.

Comment: Can you provide more information about the overall purpose of your app. Are you already using `Event` and `Company` models?

Answer (score 0):

Also, could I suggest you go right back to basics. First up, draw on a bit of paper precisely how you want the models to interact...

Do you want your model 'Foo' to have one or many 'Bars'? Or do you want Foo to have many Bars and Bars to have many Foos. If that makes sense!!

Don't write any code until you know what you exactly need.

Maybe start by watching a few of the following Railscasts:

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association-revised
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/189-embedded-association

Comment: I have gone through almost all tuts, videos, and several books. When it comes to data model relationships my brain shuts down. A Company goes a to Event they capture leads. The leads are owned by a company, but an Event also needs to know about the leads that were created.